# Why do I get a template error if I name my function `swap`, but `Swap` is okay?

Tags: c++, templates

Alright so heres the program and works absolutely right

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void Swap(T &a , T &b);

int main(){

    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;

    cout<<"i, j = " << i <<" , " <<j<<endl;
    Swap(i,j);
    cout<<"i, j = " << i <<" , " <<j<<endl;


}
template <typename T>
void Swap(T &a , T &b){
    T temp;
    temp = a ;
    a = b;
    b= temp;
}
```

but when I change the function's name from ***Swap*** to ***swap***
it generates an error saying

> error: call of overloaded 'swap(int&, int&)' is ambiguous| note:
>   candidates are: void swap(T&, T&) [with T = int]| ||=== Build
>   finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

what happened is it a rule to start functions using templates to start with a capital letter ?

Comment: Who/where has it been suggested that templated function names should start with a capital letter? I'm asking because I don't know, not because I'd disagree. Though, the standard library for example uses lower_case naming convention too, so at a quick thought I can't come up with a great benefit for such naming scheme. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because there already exists a function called `swap`. It is actually under the `std` namespace, but because you have a `using namespace std` line, it exists without the `std::` prefix.

As you can see, using the `using namespace std` isn't always a good option because of possible name collisions, as in this example. In general one should prefer not to use the `using` directive unless there's a real reason for this - namespaces exist for a reason - to prevent name collisions.